# Parent proxy with different IP protocol

Tags: squid

My machine `L` has only an IPv4 address.
I want to access a web page `S` from `L` through a VPS `P2` that has only an IPv6 address.
I have a VPS `P1` that has a single interface with two addresses: IPv4 and IPv6.

So the whole chain should be `L(IPv4) -> P1(IPv4) -> P1(IPv6) -> P2(IPv6) -> S(IPv6)`

I have installed Squid 3.3.8 on each VPS (running Ubuntu).

Here is the configuration of `P1`:

```
http_port 3128
cache_peer 2001:XXXX:XXX:XX:XXX:XXXX:XXXX:66bc parent 3128 0 no-query no-digest default
never_direct allow all
```

Here is the configuration of `P2`:

```
http_port 3128
http_access allow all
```

I get this error: `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`. It appears that there is a problem in `P1(IPv4) -> P1(IPv6)` or in `P1(IPv6) -> P2(IPv6)`. The latter is more likely, I guess. How can I fix this?

**Notes:**

- I know I can access `S` directly from `P1`. I tried it (by using `http_access allow all` instead of `never_direct allow all`). It works. But this is not what I want.
- I don't care about security now (e.g., setting restrictive ACLs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the configuration of `P1`. I should have maintained `http_access allow all`:

```
http_port 3128
cache_peer 2001:XXXX:XXX:XX:XXX:XXXX:XXXX:66bc parent 3128 0 no-query no-digest default
never_direct allow all
http_access allow all
```